# embedded ranges in AWK file

Tags: awk

I found plenty of AWK Ranges examples when passed as CLI. For example:

```
awk '/start/,/end/' file
```

How do I embed ranges in my AWK file instead?

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
}
{
   # how do I express those "start" and "end" ranges?
}
END {
}
```

My text files look something like this:

```
...
don't care
don't care
start
record of interest
record on interest
...
end
don't care
don't care
...
```

Comment: Could you clarify that a little, give an example ?

Comment: You've put the comment/question inside a "bare" action block. Do you really need it there? The natural place would be in the (now empty) pattern *ahead* of the action block.

Comment: Thank you @JeffSchaller, but I just don't follow. I'm new to awk. Is there any chance you could share an example?

Comment: I asked because I wasn't sure what your intention was by putting that comment there. I'll try an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main body of an awk script has the form:

```
*pattern* *action*
```

Where either can be omitted. Omitting the *pattern* means the *action* is always performed. Omitting the *action* defaults to printing the current line.

The natural way to express a range would be in the *pattern* section, like so:

```
BEGIN {
  somevar=5
}

/start/,/end/ { print }

END {
  somevar=6
}
```

(where I left in the BEGIN and END sections, just to keep the same structure that you started with).

To accomplish the same behavior in the *action* section requires keeping track of where you are:

```
BEGIN {
  p=0
}

{
  if (/start/) p=1
  if (p) { print }
  if (/end/) p=0
}

END {
  p=0
}
```

Here, there is no *pattern*, so the *action* block is executed for every line. We set a flag (`p`) to 1 or "true" once we see a line that matches `/start`/; if (and only if) that flag is true, we print the line. If we see the `/end`/, then reset the flag.  The BEGIN and END blocks are superfluous here; variables in awk default to zero/false.

Comment: Simply beautiful, works as a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

```
oot@localhost ~]# i=`awk '/care/{print NR}' l.txt| sort -nr| sed -n '1p'`
[root@localhost ~]# awk -v i="$i"  '/care/{x=NR+i}(NR<=x){print }' l.txt
don't care
don't care
start
record of interest
record on interest
...
end
don't care
don't care
...
```

Comment: I think you've over-answered; the question seems to be asking how to express start & end ranges inside the awk script, not how to hard-code `care` into it.